# Search in many2one field odoo

Tags: odoo, many-to-one, odoo-15

In Odoo 15, Sale order view, inside the sale order line.. we can search a product by barcode, but i want to make the search case insensitive so for example if i have two product one having barcode ='A11' and another product having a barcode ='a112' i want when i type 'a11' to get these 2 products.

the search now by odoo is case sensitive.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is implemented to search for products using the [**=** operator](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/product/models/product.py#L535), It should work if you replace it with [ilike](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#search-domains)

***Example:***

```py
class ProductProduct(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.product'

    def _search(self, args, offset=0, limit=None, order=None, count=False, access_rights_uid=None):
        if args and args[0][0] == 'barcode':
            args[0] = ('barcode', 'ilike', args[0][2])
        return super(ProductProduct, self)._search(args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, count=count,
                                                   access_rights_uid=access_rights_uid)
```

Comment: The `args[0][0]` can lead to erros, for example if the first domain leaf in `args` is `|` (or) or `&` (and). But yes, that's a way to do it, and i would probably do it similar.

Comment: Thank You for the Feedback @CZoellner. This is just to test, I would probably first check if arg is an instance of a tuple or a list before trying to access the first element.